# Should one merge a named branch into the default branch first or vice-versa?

Tags: mercurial

I have a central repo and a local repo. The repo has the "default" branch and one named branch "mybranch". If I am working in the named branch and want to occasionally merge my changes into default and then continue working in the named branch should I do this:

1. pull latest from central repo into my local repo
2. while working in mybranch, do a "`hg merge default`" to merge default INTO mybranch
3. commit locally
4. then do "`hg update default`" and "`hg merge mybranch`" to merge mybranch INTO default
5. commit locally
6. push to the central repo
   e
   OR

do same as above, but switch #2 with #4? (so that I am merging mybranch INTO default first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you have it now (merge `default` into `mybranch` first) is my preferred way.

I tend to use branches for isolating changes for a particular feature or refactoring, so it's best to bring changesets from `default` into the named branch at regular intervals. This way the named branch's changes are kept up-to-date in relation to the `default` branch.

Comment: Thanks-- I asked because in some diagrams, I have seen it the other way where you merge into default first. So I didn't know if there was a reason for this. For example: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ (this is Git, but you get my point...)

Comment: That diagram is fine because the only change that happens [almost] directly to the `master` branch is that hotfix, which is also merged into the `develop` branch. One way that could be done is to commit the hotfix changes on the `master` branch and then merge `master` into `develop`. The only reason `master` is not merged into `develop` more is because nothing is changing on `master` that needs to be integrated. Another good part to look at is the interaction between the `develop` and `release` branches in that diagram.

Comment: When I look at the interaction between "develop" and "release branches" in that diagram, it looks to me as though "develop" first gets merged into "release branches" and then "release branches" gets merged into the "develop" branch which is the opposite way that I am currently doing things (if you think of "release branches" as equivalent to "default" and "develop" as equivalent to "my branch". Am I misinterpreting that diagram?

Comment: In my shop we use `default` as our development branch and [a `stable` branch](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default/) for what is released, and then other named branches off of `default` for features (only merged into `default`, never directly into `stable`).

Comment: What you're seeing in that diagram is that the `release` branch was created from the `develop` branch. After that, bugfixes happen on the `release` branch, which are merged into the `develop` branch frequently until the `develop` branch is ready for release again.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Now, when we look at the develop branch and feature branches, are those showing the case where a feature branch gets merged into develop and then (after develop is merged into release branches) develop is merged into the feature branch? If we were following your model AND our feature was being developed over a long period of time, we might ALSO See the develop branch being merged down INTO the feature branch for purposes of the feature branch not getting too out of sync with the develop branch. Correct?

Comment: .. and also let's say that we only care about the case where we want to push something out to default from our named branch... and we NEVER have merged default INTO our named branch before, should we first do that merge (in case there are any merge issues we want to resolve) and then do the merge into default? (I am assuming YES, but I want clarification).

Comment: You had 3 things there, the second and third are correct, but that diagram does not show the develop branch being merged back into a feature branch after the feature was merged into the develop branch. Instead of hashing out examples ad nauseum, here's the rule of thumb: You don't want a branch (such as a feature) and the branch it is based on to get too divergent because the merge will be more difficult later. You can't keep merging unfinished work into the 'parent' branch, so you go the other way. Then you integrate the finished work.

Answer (score 16):

You write that you

> want to occasionally merge my changes into default and then continue working in the named branch

You should normally not merge the feature branch into the `default` branch, unless the feature is done. Maybe that is what you meant?

Just for reference, the recommended workflow is to do

1. Create feature branch
2. Do your work there
3. Regularly (every couple of days) merge changes from `default` into the feature branch:

   1. `hg pull` to get the latest changes from the other developers
   2. `hg merge` to integrate the latest changes into your feature branch
4. When the feature branch is all done, you merge it back into `default`:

   1. `hg pull`
   2. `hg update default` to checkout the branch you want to merge into
   3. `hg merge myfeature` to do the merge

The final merge will be very small since the regular merges of `default` into the feature branch makes sure that there is only a small distance from the two branch heads back to a common ancestor.

Comment: That's true if your "features" are sufficiently small. But many of us do features incrementally, completing pieces to a reasonable standard even if not totally "done".